# How to obtain from a custom switch component its current state value on my react-hook-forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I have a custom Switch component that I want to use for my forms in react-native. The dilemma I have is how to obtain from this switch component its current state value.

I got a version of the switch working on this component:

```
/** @format */

// BASE
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Platform,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Switch,
} from 'react-native';

// CONSTANTS
import Styles from '../../../../constants/Styles';

// TYPE
import SubtitleOne from '../../../type/SubtitleOne';

// COMPONENTS
import ListItem from '../ListItem/ListItem';

export default function SingleLineWithSwitch(props) {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(props.value);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <ListItem onPress={() => toggleSwitch()}>
      <View style={Styles.listSingleCointainer}>
        <SubtitleOne style={Styles.listTitle}>{props.title}</SubtitleOne>
        <View style={Styles.listSwitchView}>
          <Switch
            thumbColor={props.thumbColor}
            trackColor={props.trackColor}
            style={Styles.switchControl}
            value={isEnabled}
            onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

On my form Screen I have this:

```
<Controller
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
          <SingleLineWithSwitch
            title='Visible'
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
        )}
        name='visible'
      />
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Kapobajza I edited the question for better comprehension. The dilemma I have is how to obtain from this switch component its current state value in my react-forms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lift the state `isEnabled` up to you parent component, that is your form.

This could look as follows.

```js
export default function SingleLineWithSwitch(props) {
  const isEnabled = props.enabled;
  const setIsEnabled = props.setIsEnabled;
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <ListItem onPress={() => toggleSwitch()}>
      <View style={Styles.listSingleCointainer}>
        <SubtitleOne style={Styles.listTitle}>{props.title}</SubtitleOne>
        <View style={Styles.listSwitchView}>
          <Switch
            thumbColor={props.thumbColor}
            trackColor={props.trackColor}
            style={Styles.switchControl}
            value={isEnabled}
            onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

Then, in your form

```js
const [enabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(value)
<Controller
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
          <SingleLineWithSwitch
            title='Visible'
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            enabled={enabled}
            setIsEnabled={setIsEnabled}
          />
        )}
        name='visible'
  />
```

Comment: But does that work for multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Sure, keep an array of `enabled` states.

Comment: I tried this example, and when I submit the form, the field visible returns undefined. I don't think react-form-hook is capturing the value of that component.

Comment: I tried your example, gives undefined output

```javascript
Object {
  "iconUrl": "ddd",
  "maxParticipants": "2",
  "minParticipants": "2",
  "name": "ddd",
  "visible": undefined,
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a problem in your form setup than in the problem of using a state value of a child component in its parent. From the code that you have provided, I do not think that I can debug this. Can you share a minimal example which you expect to work but doesn't?